# How to Parse Json children in VB.NET Newtonsoft (follow-up )

Tags: vb.net, json, parsing

New to JSon, I have learned how to do basic JSon parings (learning from this question and the answers: [How to Parse Json children in VB.NET Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982358/how-to-parse-json-children-in-vb-net-newtonsoft).

Thanks to this question and answer I have managed to read similar data using VB.Net

But my data is slightly different what comes to the sub-items - it has extra brackets and I have not found a way how to read the sub-items.

ps: I have modified the Json in the original question to demonstrate this -

```
"CcFull": [

     [      
        {
          "Email": "sample.cc@emailDomain.com",
          "Name": "John Sample"
        }
     ] ,
     [
            {
          "Email": "another.cc@emailDomain.com",
          "Name": "Mike Sample"
                }
     ] 
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your JSON is slightly different than that which I answered in the referenced question, you have to parse things a bit differently.

Your "CcFull" object is actually an array of arrays, denoted by the `[` and `]` brackets. Since the first symbol after the colon is an open bracket it indicates an array. The next symbol is also an open bracket, so it's an array of arrays.

To dereference this with the Json.Net objects, we have to get the item value as a `JArray` object. We can then iterate over the array values in that object, just as in the other question. Something like this:

```
Dim results As List(Of JToken) = o.Children().ToList
For Each item As JProperty In results
    item.CreateReader()
    Select Case item.Name
        Case "CC"
            Dim strCC = item.Value.ToString

        Case "CcFull"
            Dim ccArray As JArray = item.Value    'Get the top-level array
            Dim strEmail As String
            Dim strName As String
            For Each subitem As JObject In ccArray.Values
                strEmail = subitem("Email")
                strName = subitem("Name")
            Next
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest that, when you get a question correctly answered, you mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark under the answer. That's the general practice as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/about. It gives the persons that answer reputation points and spreads the good karma.