# I am having trouble parsing Json using VB.NET using the Newtonsoft Json.Net library

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

```
{
  "data": {
    "chat": {
      "id": "e824dc29-68ea-41a4-b69e-60fe31226e43",
      "messageList": [
        {
          "id": "954a7544-d1cf-4580-a546-82b8d4c03771",
          "data": {
            "__typename": "ChatMessageDataText",
            "message": "huys guys .. thanks u,,,"
          },
          "createdAt": "Mon, 27 Jun 2022 03:48:53 GMT",
          "user": {
            "id": "a4a52bfe-43c2-42a9-bd01-b8cdf6fa13e5",
            "name": "Sellama",
            "isMuted": false,
            "isRainproof": false,
            "isIgnored": false,
            "isHighroller": false,
            "isSportHighroller": false,
            "leaderboardDailyProfitRank": null,
            "leaderboardDailyWageredRank": null,
            "leaderboardWeeklyProfitRank": null,
            "leaderboardWeeklyWageredRank": null,
            "flags": [
              {
                "flag": "bronze",
                "rank": 1,
                "createdAt": "Fri, 24 Sep 2021 16:37:32 GMT",
                "__typename": "UserFlag"
              },
              {
                "flag": "silver",
                "rank": 2,
                "createdAt": "Sat, 27 Nov 2021 06:59:43 GMT",
                "__typename": "UserFlag"
              },
              {
                "flag": "gold",
                "rank": 3,
                "createdAt": "Thu, 20 Jan 2022 09:20:40 GMT",
                "__typename": "UserFlag"
              },
              {
                "flag": "platinum",
                "rank": 4,
                "createdAt": "Sun, 03 Apr 2022 02:39:16 GMT",
                "__typename": "UserFlag"
              }
            ],
            "roles": [],
            "createdAt": "Mon, 26 Apr 2021 03:20:00 GMT",
            "__typename": "User"
          },
          "__typename": "ChatMessage"
        }
      ],
      "__typename": "Chat"
    }
  }
}
```

I can get a valid JObject thus:

`Dim check As JObject = JObject.Parse(strJson)`

Then I can get list of a JTokens and iterate through them and easily get the root item values - but how get the Child records for strJson?

```
Dim dataku As List(Of JToken) = check.Children().ToList

            For Each item As JProperty In dataku
                item.CreateReader()
                Select Case item.Name
                    Case "data"
                        For Each item1 As JProperty In item
                            item1.CreateReader()
                            Select Case item1.Name
                                Case "chat"
                                    For Each item2 As JProperty In item
                                        item2.CreateReader()
                                        Select Case item2.Name
                                            Case "messageList"
                                                For Each subitem As JObject In item1.Values
                                                    TextBox1.Text = subitem("user")

                                                Next
                                        End Select
                                    Next
                            End Select
                        Next
                End Select
            Next
```

It seems like I might be able to use a JArray or parse the item.value - but the syntax eludes me.

I don't want to setup a whole strongly typed model in VB and do an automatic deserialze - prefer more like the Dynamic way of doing it in C# - or preferably just iterate over n children for the CcFull node and pluck out the values for Email and Name and put them in a generic list.

Seems there are no good VB.NET examples on SO or by Googling.

C# has totally simple ways to do this - but I'm stuck in VB.NET for this project.

Comment: Could always try using the Paste Special -> Json as classes option in Visual Studio which will give you a strongly typed class structure which means you can deserialize your json directly to a list(of Data) then you can just walk through the property chain to get to what you need without all the JObject stuff

Comment: thank u hursey i like u sir

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15982674/7120031) and [the follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15989423/7120031). Your question seems like a pretty close duplicate.