# Parse Json in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I have the following Json which I wish to loop through in vb.net and extract the questions and results.  I have attempted to use Newtonsoft.json but I get errors although JSONlint validates the Json. What is the correct method to achieve this?

```
{
    "Vehicle_Check": [
        19,
        {
            "question": "Brakes",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Water Levels",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Horn",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Washers",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Wipers",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Indicators",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Reflectors",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Oil Levels",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Lights",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Mirrors",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Steering",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Tyres Wheels",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Battery",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Fuel or Oil Leaks",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        },
        {
            "question": "Other",
            "result": "OK",
            "Fault": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The code I am using to parse the Json is:

```
Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(VCItem.Check)
Dim results As List(Of JToken) = o.Children().ToList
For Each item As JProperty In results
    item.CreateReader()
    Select Case item.Name
        'process data here
    End Select
Next
```

This returns the last element only:

```
{[
    19,
    {
        "question": "Other",
        "result": "OK",
        "Fault": ""
    }
]}
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: Can we see the code you tried to use to do the deserialization?

Comment: @user1898898 you should edit your question and put the code there, not in a comment.

Comment: What is inside the `Select Case` code? What are you storing the result  of the `process data here` logic into, a variable? In other words, what holds "only" the last element?

Comment: item.Name holds:  {[
    19,
    {
        "question": "Other",
        "result": "OK",
        "Fault": ""
    }
]}

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is returning the first and last elements. Given what you posted, 19 is the first item in the array, which is not proper anyway.

Try this (yes, it looks horrid I know) But I had to also remove the 19 from the list as it is not an object but a string. Your array has different types in it and you would need to test to the string if it had to stay. I am working on a better way to Read JSON myself, but it is taking longer than I had hoped.

```
    Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(VCItem)
    Dim results As List(Of JToken) = o.Children().ToList
    For Each item As JProperty In results
        item.CreateReader()
        If item.Value.Type = JTokenType.Array Then
            Dim results2 As List(Of JToken) = item.Value.ToList
            For Each subitem As JObject In results2
                Dim results3 As List(Of JToken) = subitem.Children().ToList
                For Each temp2 As JProperty In results3
                    temp2.CreateReader()
                    MsgBox(temp2.Name)
                    MsgBox(temp2.Value)
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Found a simpler way to display your values, but still depends on the structure of the JSON string (found the simpler way here: [How to Parse Json children in VB.NET Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982358/how-to-parse-json-children-in-vb-net-newtonsoft))

```
    Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(VCItem)
    Dim results As List(Of JToken) = o.Children().ToList
    For Each item As JProperty In results
        item.CreateReader()
        If item.Value.Type = JTokenType.Array Then
            For Each subitem As JObject In item.Values
                MsgBox(subitem("question"))
                MsgBox(subitem("result"))
                MsgBox(subitem("Fault"))
            Next
        End If
    Next
```