# How do you get Json List items with vbnet

Tags: json, vb.net

Hi I'm trying to get a list of all the items from a Json String
Please be gentle I'm a total programming dummy lol
Ive searched till I'm blue in the face all over but found the best example on here [How to Parse Json children in VB.NET Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982358/how-to-parse-json-children-in-vb-net-newtonsoft) but after trying allsorts I can only get the first lot of items from "result"
But I need all the Items from "nilfromhere"
Here is the Json string lookalike

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"result1":"noproblem1","result2":"noproblem2","nilfromhere":[{"thisone":000,"andthis":"nodice","needthis":0.0,"andthis":1}]}],"maybethis":1}

Here is what I have (Ive tried switching them around also but still only get front results)

```
 Dim strJson As String = txtTester.Text
    Dim obj As JObject = JObject.Parse(strJson)
    Dim results As List(Of JToken) = obj.Children().ToList
    Dim strStart As String = ""
    Dim strOutput1 As String = ""
    Dim strOutput2 As String = ""
    For Each item As JProperty In results
        item.CreateReader()
        Select Case item.Name
            Case "jsonrpc"
                Dim strVersion As String = ""
                strVersion = item.Value.ToString
                strStart = strVersion  'Returns 2.0 so no need to be a double etc
            Case "result"
                Dim Result1 As String = ""
                Dim Result2 As String = ""
                'Dim NilFromHere as String >>> Cant convert an Array to string error when tried up here
                '~~> All these work fine below up to the nilfromhere string
                For Each resultItem As JObject In item.Values
                    Result1 = resultItem("result1") 'Returns "noproblem1"
                    Result2 = resultItem("result2") 'Returns "noproblem2"
                    ' Dim ResultTry As Object = resultItem("nilfromhere").ToString '= Error as expected!
                    ' Dim ResultTry2 As Object = resultItem("thisone").ToString '= Error as expected!
                Next
                strOutput1 += Result1 + vbTab + Result2 + vbCrLf
                'Below returns nothing but no errors! I need all the items from "nilfromhere" 
            Case "nilfromhere" ' Tried this here as it looks identical to the first one
                Dim Thisone As Object = Nothing 'Tried object because its an integer but 2.0 works ok above
                Dim AndThis As String = ""
                'Get nothing here
                For Each Iwish As JObject In item.Values
                    Thisone = Iwish("thisone").ToString 'Number values but dont think thats the problem?
                    AndThis = Iwish("andthis").ToString
                    'Other Items etc
                Next
                strOutput2 += Thisone + vbTab + AndThis + vbCrLf
                '*** Try as an array but returns same as above - Nothing but no errors!
                Dim IwishArray As JArray = item.Value    'Get the top-level array?
                For Each IwishArrayItem As JObject In IwishArray.Values
                    Thisone = IwishArrayItem("thisone")
                    AndThis = IwishArrayItem("thisone")
                Next
                strOutput2 += Thisone + vbTab + AndThis + vbCrLf
        End Select
    Next
    MsgBox(strStart)
    MsgBox(strOutput1)
    MsgBox(strOutput2)
```

I would really be grateful if anybody could help me out here
Thanks a lot in advance
Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than attempting to parse the json, manually, you should let the Json library do all of the work.

You do this by defining a class structure that matches the Json you are trying to parse and then asking the json library to deserialize the json string into that class structure. It will take care of all of the necessary work, such as type conversion and instantiating arrays or lists of objects without any additional work from you.

Here is a working example based on your json string (I had to change the second andthis to andthis1 to make it work correctly):

The top level class:

```
public class TopLevel
{
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    public List<SecondLevel> result { get; set; }
}
```

The second level class (contained in the array result above):

```
public class SecondLevel
{
    public string result1 { get; set; }
    public string result2 { get; set; }
    public List<ThirdLevel> nilfromhere { get; set; }
    public int maybethis { get; set; }
}
```

The third level class (the array of objects stored in nillfromhere):

```
public class ThirdLevel
{
    public int thisone { get; set; }
    public string andthis { get; set; }
    public decimal needthis { get; set; }
    public int andthis1 { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, the deserialization code:

```
const string json = @"{""jsonrpc"":""2.0"",""result"":[{""result1"":""noproblem1"",""result2"":""noproblem2"",""nilfromhere"":[{""thisone"":000,""andthis"":""nodice"",""needthis"":0.0,""andthis1"":1}]}],""maybethis"":1}";

var jsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TopLevel>(json);

Debug.WriteLine(jsonObject.result[0].nilfromhere[0].andthis);
```

Comment: I cant find a way to say thanks on here but THANKS although I can only do vbnet I just converted this with http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=5d2316d8-73fc-4fcc-b029-0ef7404db8f2 and I applied it a real world string and it works perfectly -- I can now play at my speed - Brilliant - I think I voted right Cheers

Comment: An extra problem has occurred - How could i create a property with the name "event" as this is a Keyword in vbnet? I have tried using the escape brackets as such-- Public Property [event] As List(Of stuff) instead of Public Property event() As List but Json is taking it as an array! I need to return from here---> }],"event":{"id":"271","name":”rty” etc Cheers in advance

Comment: You can call the property anything that you want (i.e. MyEvent) so that the app will compile and then add the Json.Net attribute JsonProperty directly above the property name specifying the name of the property in Json. For example: [JsonProperty("event")].

Comment: Cheers competent_tech that has helped me no end as it is now possible to even refer to a Class with a Keyword as well by enclosing both in the vbnet keyword escape brackets [] my example used was  [code] <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="event")> _
        Public Property [Event]() As [Event]
            Get
                Return m_Event
            End Get
            Set(value As [Event])
                m_Event = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Event As [Event] Cheers again