# Using json.net, how do I query within embedded arrays?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

First, I'm referencing this: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SelectToken.htm

I'm using json.net

If I get a post response that returns the following:

```
{
    "success_count": 1,
    "error_count": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "status": "example status",
            "member_rating": 42

        }
    ]
}
```

And I've stored that into a variable called "as_Read"

I can do the following:

```
Dim as_ReadJobj As JObject = JObject.Parse(as_Read)
Dim as_SuccessCountValue = as_ReadJobj.Property("success_count").Value
Dim as_ErrorCountValue = as_ReadJobj.Property("error_count").Value
```

What I can't seem to understand is how to query the value of status.

I've tried:

```
Dim as_SubscribeStatus = as_ReadJobj.SelectToken("data[0].status").Value
Dim as_SubscribeStatus = as_ReadJobj.Property("data")("status").Value
```

And a few other methods. It seems like I'm just blind to something obvious, but I'm new to vb.net and just started using this json library.

Thank you!

---

Update: I figured it out.

I accepted an answer, as that solution worked perfectly. I also figured out my original problem. The following works:

```
as_SubscribeStatus = as_ReadJobj.SelectToken("data[0].status").ToString
```

I guess I didn't understand the inner workings of SelectToken enough. But now I have two solutions. Awesome.

Comment: Is the curly bracket in your first not working example a typo? Because that looks like it should work with both square brackets there

Comment: @Starscream1984 - It was a typo. Sorry :)

Comment: I get "Type parameter 'U' for extension method 'Public Function Value(Of U)() As U' in Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extentions cannot be inferred.

Comment: This is driving me bonkers. I've gone through tons of examples and apparently I'm an idiot.

Comment: So the error "Type parameter 'U'..." can be fixed by just passing a string. I see that the solution is indicated in the Json.NET webpage you've linked above. If only they did have a VB.NET counterpart example, we should have fixed this earlier lol

Comment: No doubt. Few hours of headache for such a simple solution. I wish someone would jump on that project and translate to vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list of JToken to do that and iterate through the items of that list to extract the information you want, including the embedded arrays.

```
Dim asRead As String = "{""success_count"": 1,""error_count"": 0,""data"": [{""status"": ""example status"",""member_rating"": 42}]}"

        Dim as_ReadJobj As JObject = JObject.Parse(asRead)

        Dim results As List(Of JToken) = as_ReadJobj.Children().ToList

        Dim as_SuccessCountValue As String
        Dim as_ErrorCountValue As String
        Dim status As String = ""
        Dim member_rating As String = ""

        For Each item As JProperty In results
            item.CreateReader()
            Select Case item.Name
                Case "success_count"
                    as_SuccessCountValue = item.Value.ToString
                Case "error_count"
                    as_ErrorCountValue = item.Value.ToString
                Case "data"
                    For Each subitem As JObject In item.Values
                        status = subitem("status")
                        member_rating = subitem("member_rating")
                    Next
            End Select
        Next
```

I've edited the code from [another question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982358/how-to-parse-json-children-in-vb-net-newtonsoft). I have not yet tried to use `.SelectToken` but the code above should fulfill the requirements you supplied.

Note:

I've used a string for status and member_rating whereas they should really be a `list of string`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and at the same time I also figured out what I was doing wrong previously... literally around the time you posted this, so thank you. I will mark yours as correct but also edit my question to show you.